# reached max size for compiled sql statement cache for database

Tags: android, sqlite, max-size

I have the following error:

```
reached max size for compiled sql statement cache for database  no space for this 
sql statement in cache select number  code status time id from contacts number 
please change your sql statements to use "?" for bindargs of using actual values
```

This is my code:

```
    public long updateNumber(String NUMBER,String CODE,String STATUS,String TIME){
    ContentValues initialValuesCode = new ContentValues();
    initialValuesCode.put(codeOperator, CODE);
    initialValuesCode.put(status, STATUS);
    initialValuesCode.put(time,TIME);
    String prom="0"+NUMBER.substring(0,8);

    return db.update(Database_Table_Number, initialValuesCode, "NUMBER=?", new       String[{prom});

}


public Cursor getNumberById(String id_par)
{

   return db.query(Database_Table_Number, new String[]{number,codeOperator,status,time,id}, "_ID=?", new String[]{id_par}, null, null, null);
       }
      public Cursor getAllNumbers()
      {
   return db.query(Database_Table_Number, new String[]{number}, null, null, number, null, null);
      }
      public Cursor getAllContacts() 
  {
    return db.query(Database_Table_Name, new String[] {id,name}, null, null, null, null, "DISPLAY_NAME asc" );

}
  public Cursor getDate(String byid){
    return db.query(Database_Table_Number, new String[] {time}, "_ID=="+byid, null, null, null, null);
}
   public Cursor isEpmty(){
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ContactsName", null);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

where does this happen. i see a lot of errors in your sqlite queries...

this maybe gives you the ? issue:

```
 "_ID=="+byid
```

should be:

```
 ...,"_ID=?",new String[]{byid},...
```